# Each with index up to a certain number ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Silly question I think, but I've searched high and low for a definitive answer on this and found nothing.

```
array.each_with_index |row, index|
  puts index
end
```

Now, say I only want to print the first ten items of the array.

```
array.each_with_index |row, index|
  if (index>9)
     break;
  end
   puts index
end
```

Is there a better way than this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#take`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-take):

```
array.take(10).each_with_index |row, index|
   puts index
end
```

If the condition is more complicated, use [`take_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-take_while).

The rule of thumb is: iterators might be chained:

```
array.take(10)
     .each
   # .with_object might be chained here or there too!
     .with_index |row, index|
   puts index
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use [Enumerable#first](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-first)

```
array.first(10).each_with_index do |row, index|
  puts index
end
```